# jQuery Mobile ListView-Item click causes multiple click-events

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, backbone.js

A click on the ListItem causes multiple click events in a row, although I only click once.

This is my ListItem:

[image: ListViewItem]

```
<a data-transition="slide" class="folderSelectedButton" id=<%=fullPath%>>
     <div class="thumbContainer">
         <img class="imgListThumb" src="images/FolderDark.png">
     </div>
     <h3><%=name%></h3>
     <p>Folder</p>
     <a data-icon=....></>
 </a>
```

I catch/bind the event in the view:

```
 events:
    {
        "click .folderSelectedButton"   : "folderSelected"
    },
```

The function I want to call is defined:

```
folderSelected: function(ev)
{
    fbsCollection.update(ev.currentTarget.id);
    this.render();
}
```

I also try to catch

```
ev.target.id
```

but then I get the Ids of the h3-tag or p-tag if I hit them. That doesn't work at all

EDIT: JQM Settings

```
$.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false;
$.mobile.linkBindingEnabled = false;
$.mobile.hashListeningEnabled = false;
$.mobile.pushStateEnabled = false;
$.mobile.autoInitializePage = false;
```

The behaviour is more odd. Every time I open a new List-Item it produces an additional click-event. First items causes only one event, the second item two events .. and so on

Comment: how do you bind click event? Do you bind to any page event?

Comment: I updated the quetion: I bind the events by the backbone view

Comment: do you have `$.mobile.linkBindingEnabled` disabled?

Comment: If I don't disable it, the links don't work at all

Comment: I guess this has to do with backbone events binding. if you add 5 items and get 5 click responses, then backbone is multiplying click binding on that selector.

Comment: Do you have any idea how I can awoid that?

Comment: The behaviour is more odd. Every time I open a new List-Item it produces an additional click-event. First items causes only one event, the second item two events .. and so on

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42878/discussion-between-omar-and-marcel)

Comment: can you post the code of your View? and how you instantiate your view? it's possible that you are binding the same events to a set of elements by selector whenever a new view element is created.

Comment: I found a solution: $(this.el).off('click', '.folderSelectedButton');
I added this in a close-Function of the view. It seems as if the click -event gets bounded to the el-element, and is always added I rerender the view.

Comment: Is this solution either a good or a bad way?